# PHP version is getting default in laravel when I replace the files with previous one

Tags: php, laravel

I am updating the system, by extracting the files and folders of my project which includes vendor, composer.js, composer.lock file and after that I am getting this 7.4 version shown.

But I've set the PHP version 8.2

I've tried to change my .htaccess to


Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Use PHP 8.0.2
<IfModule mod_php8.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php8 .php
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu, consider running these commands:

a2enmod enables the specific module & a2dismod used to disable a specific module.

```
php -v
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo a2dismod php8.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: But I don't want to use the CLI or exec() function, I want to create a program dynamic that can be updated by extracting the zip file of the app.
But when I do this, it is getting the default PHP version of the domain.
I have installed it on a subdomain.